# Can i link the google assistant sdk with the google home app?

Tags: android, google-home, google-assistant-sdk

I recently setup google assistant on my windows pc and my raspberry pi. But i noticed that it couldn't play music as it says please connect to the google home app to choose a default music player. So i was wondering if there is any possible way in which i can connect my assistant to the google home app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not with the alphav1 version of the api. According to the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/release-notes) this feature is coming soon.